# Android Realm one to many relationship, query

Tags: android, realm, relationship, one-to-many, realm-mobile-platform

I have two classes:

```
public class Employee extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    String name
    Department department;

    //getters setters etc.
}

public class Department extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    int id;
    String name;

    //getters setters etc.
}
```

It is one to many relationship. One department can have multiple employees. I've tried to make some queries.

```
realm.where(Employee.class).equalTo("department.name", "deptName").findAll()
realm.where(Department.class).equalTo("employee.name", "empName").findAll()
```

The first one is working, the second one has an error:

Invalid query: employee does not refer to a class.

How to make the second one work? Do I must make a RealmList of Employees in Department class?

I wanted in this query fetch all Departments which have an Employee with specified name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realm 3.5.0+:

```
public class Employee extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    String name
    Department department;

    //getters setters etc.
}

public class Department extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    int id;
    String name;

    @LinkingObjects("department")
    private final RealmResults<Employee> employees = null;
    //getters setters etc.
}
realm.where(Employee.class).equalTo("department.name", "deptName").findAll()
realm.where(Department.class).equalTo("employees.name", "empName").findAll()
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to old version of realm.

Comment: What if I just want to know all Departments that have employees not empty?

Comment: `realm.where(Department.class).isNotEmpty("employees").findAll()` should work